# Algorithm to find all possible combinations of a group of LEGOs?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, combinatorial-geometry

The other day I walked by a LEGO store in The Mall I was shopping at, and it brought back some memories. Then that got me thinking: There's got to be some mathematical algorithm to find all the possible combinations of any given group of LEGO pieces. (If you don't know what LEGOs are, see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego)). I'm not great in the math department, but I was wondering if anyone's already  come up with something like this, or if someone could. I just thought this would be an interesting idea.

Edit: I understand that this is quite a bit more difficult than I thought when I originally proposed the idea, so for the sake of simplification, suppose that they're just regular 2x4 legos of the same color. The number of them would be 2. After that we could try 3 to see if our algorithm works.

Comment: That is far too wide a question.  How many bricks? Which size? Do colours matter? Put together in what way?   You might want to look at [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=LEGO&language=english&go=Search)

Comment: This is a remarkably hard problem, one which LEGO themselves got incorrect once upon a time.  See [this link](http://web.math.ku.dk/~eilers/lego.html).

Comment: You might want to look for articles on the number of polyominoes of a given size. This Lego question will have similar difficulties and techniques, but is even harder.

Comment: @JMoravitz That particular case of the number of ways, counted up to symmetry, to build a contiguous building with $n$ LEGO blocks of size $2 \times 4$ is [OEIS A112389](https://oeis.org/A112389)

Comment: Although the question is interesting, it would be good to narrow it down and make it less broad. Can you please do this?